# 'list' object has no attribute 'info'

Tags: python, list, class

In a class, I have the following code:

```
class Player (object):
    def __init__ (self, first, last):
        '''the constructor for a player'''
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.rating = 0
        self.info = []


    def update(self, pos, team, year, att, yards, tds, fumbles ):
        '''create a list of information for this player for this year and 
        append it to the info field. Then call calcrating.'''
        self.info = self.info.append(year, pos, team, att, yards, tds, fumbles)
```

In the program, I use the following code to call the update function of the class:

```
playerDict[playerName] = Player.update(line[0:2],line[2],line[3],line[13],\
                                       line[5],line[6],line[7],line[10])
```

`playerDict` as well as `playerName` have been defined, no worries there.  However, whenever I try to run the program and update the `playerName`, it gives me `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'info'`

On Python's website guide, its code for empty lists in the constructor and updating it is exactly what mine is, but mine doesn't work. Is there any way to get around this error?

Comment: `Player.update` looks like you are calling the function statically. You want to call it on an instance

Comment: you should just do `self.info.append` and get rid of the `self.info =` before

Comment: FWIW, you'll need to change self.info = self.info.append(year, pos, team, att, yards, tds, fumbles) to self.info.append(yr,pos,team,etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not instantiating the `Player` class. Therefore when you call `update` the instance `self` is not automagically passed as parameter to the `update` method, and thus one of the arguments (a list) takes its place.

This should work:

```
player = Player()  # first instantiate
player.update(...)  # then do your stuff
```

Note: AFAIK, this only happens in Python 3. In Python 2.x there is a typecheck for `self`.

By the way, this line won't work either.

```
self.info = self.info.append(year, pos, team, att, yards, tds, fumbles)
```

Check the [`list.append`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) docs.

Comment: I'll take out the `self.info =` part, I had used that as a back up try.  I'll try the new Player call

Comment: I made the player switch, but now the append line isn't working because there is more than 1 argument.  Do I just have to make a bunch of append statements?

Comment: Update: I made my append a list of the arguments, and now it all works except the list isn't showing up as the value to the `playerDict[playerName]`

Comment: If you haven't changed your code, the value stored in `playerDict` is the instance of `Player`, not the list itself.

Comment: How do I make the value of `playerDict[playerName]` the list from the update function of the `Player` instance

Comment: You could do `playerDict[playerName] = player.info`.